# How to view email source in Yahoo! mail

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, yahoo

I'm getting CSS rendering issues in Yahoo! mail in IE8. How can I view the email source? I've tried installing the IE dev toolbar but the message body is within an iframe which doesn't provide any useful information.

In case it's a common issue, has anyone else had problems with inline CSS classes not being used in IE with Yahoo? In Firefox it looks fine, but the same email in IE has all font formatting ignored (aside from the basics like "bold" or "italic").

Answer (score 0):

The IE developer tools are rubbish, even in IE9. Any web inspector tools other than IE9 ones will help you (view the source).

- Opera Dragonfly
- Firefox Firebug addon
- Webkit Inspector

In future refer to the [Email Standards Project.](http://www.email-standards.org/)

Comment: The problem is the issue only occurs in IE, so I need an IE debugger